# WM_DPICHANGED not received when "scaling performed by application"

Tags: windows, dpi

I run a program (call it prog.exe) on two monitors with different DPIs, under Windows 10 (1703).
The program contains :

```
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
CreateWindow(....);
```

The prog.exe manifest contains no reference to

```
<dpiAware>...</dpiAware>
```

If prog.exe -> properties -> compatibility -> "Override High DPI scaling" is unchecked, the window receives WM_DPICHANGED when moved from a monitor to the other, and prog.exe can rescale it.
Now, if I check "Override High DPI scaling" and set it to "scaling performed by application", the window no longer receives WM_DPICHANGED (confirmed with spy++), so prog.exe doesn't know when it has to rescale it.
This seems weird : it is when the scaling is performed by the application that the application should be warned of DPI changes !
The solution to my problem could be simply : leave "Override High DPI scaling" unchecked, but things are more involved :
prog.exe (Override High DPI scaling now unchecked) is launched as a subprocess by xemacs (via comint), and the only way of having xemacs text unblurry is to set its compatibility to "scaling performed by application". But then its subprocess prog.exe is considered as PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE (confirmed by processExplorer and also by showing the result of  GetProcessDpiAwareness in prog.exe). Same situation as when "Override High DPI scaling" was checked.
I also tried to reset the dpi awareness of prog.exe with SetProcessDpiAwareness or SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext, but I got an error "access denied" : logical, since MSDN says that, once the process dpi awareness has been set, it cannot be changed thereafter.
The problem is : how can prog.exe be launched with a "fresh" DPI awareness, not inherited from its father process ?

Comment: The compatibility hack is useful for apps that *don't* declare themselves dpiAware but get it right by accident anyway.  Maybe someday they'll add yet another one to force per-monitor awareness, but I certainly wouldn't hold my breath for it.  So you simply need to stop using it.

Comment: So your program is PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE but it isn't receiving WM_DPICHANGED when you move it between monitors with different DPI?

Comment: @Hans the problem is that I didn't find another solution to have xemacs considered as per monitor dpi aware. I tried to add a Manifest to xemacs.exe resources (with Resource Hacker), but regardless of the dpiAware (true/PM) or dpiAwareness (PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor) I specify in the resource, xemacs is always considered as dpi unaware (as indicated by Process Explorer). And the edited text in xemacs is blurry !

Comment: @Hans the problem is that I didn't find another solution to have xemacs considered as per monitor dpi aware. I tried to add a Manifest to xemacs.exe resources (with Resource Hacker), but regardless of the dpiAware (true/PM) or dpiAwareness (PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor) I specify in the resource, xemacs is always considered as dpi unaware (as indicated by Process Explorer). This makes my subprocess prog.exe work correctly, but the edited text in xemacs is blurry !

Comment: You should not have to *add* a manifest, it should already be there to declare itself compatible with UAC.  Look for "requestedExecutionLevel".  But I don't know, xemacs is pretty dead with no release in the past 8 years.  Kinda weird to be talking about a fake "prog.exe" with a SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext() call when this is actually xemacs that you need to hack with resource hacker.  Best not to tell fake stories.

Comment: @hans Sorry, I am puzzled by the process of "edit comments". To recap, till now I only found two (unsatisfactory) solutions : 1- set xemacs compatibility to "scaling performed by application" : xemacs is per monitor dpi aware, the edited text is crisp, but the subprocess prog.exe doesn't receive WM_DPICHANGED.   2- leave xemacs compatibility unchecked : regardless of xemacs manifest xemacs is dpi unaware, prog.exe receives WM_DPICHANGED, but the edited text is blurry.

Comment: Well, I didn't tell the whole story... Yes, xemacs is an old timer, but I have developed a programming environment around it (I mainly program in OCaml, using C only for graphics, where OCaml is rather limited). Until recently everything worked fine on my laptop under windows XP. But it died and I had to buy a new one, with windows 10, and now everything goes wrong. All my tools are broken, and I try to bring them to work again. My fake prog.exe is an attempt to summarize the main issue I run into

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I then went to my project settings in Visual Studio and disabled DPI Awareness. The API call then succeeded and did not give access denied error.

[image: VS Project Settings]